# $.bind() on SVG elements breaks when new SVG replaces original

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, svg

I have an svg with elements that I am binding to clicks and keyups. If the user edits a text field on the page, it updates the corresponding text element in the svg. And vice versa, if the user edits the svg, it updates the corresponding text field in the html. Using jQuery.

A button on the page lets the user remove the svg from the DOM and add a different svg in its place (asynchronously). This new svg has the same elements as the first one, it just has a different graphical design.

After loading this second svg, the bindings stop working. I reinitialize everything -- unbinding and rebinding -- by calling AB.init() below but still the user can't edit the svg. How do I fix this?

UPDATE: all .bind()s are now .delegate()s per @Pointy's comment. However the problem persists. Is my .delegate() syntax valid for the namespace?

```
AB = {
  svgns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

  f: {
      field1: {svg:null, jq:null},
      field2: {svg:null, jq:null}
  },

  /* last activated text field */       
  active:   undefined,

  init: function() {
    AB.f.field1.jq = $('#id_field_1');
    AB.f.field2.jq = $('#id_field_2');
    var svg_container = document.getElementById('svg_container');
    var svg_text_elements = svg_container.getElementsByTagNameNS(svgns, 'text');
    var length = svg_text_elements.length;
    for(var i=0; i < length; i++) {
      var e = svg_text_elements[i];
      if(e.id) {
        AB.set_svg_for_text_field(e);
      } else {
        var tspans = e.getElementsByTagName('tspan');
        for(var j = 0; j < tspans.length; j++) {
          var t = tspans[j];
          AB.set_svg_for_text_field(t);
        }
      }
    }
    AB.delegate_and_display_text_fields();
  },

  delegate_and_display_text_fields: function() {
    a = [];
    $.each(AB.f, function(key, value) {
      if(value.svg && value.jq){
        $('form').delegate('input', 'keyup click', function() {
          value.svg.textContent = value.jq.val();
          CB.set_active_element(key);
          CB.active = value;
        });
        $('#svg_container svg').delegate('text', 'keyup click', function() {
          value.svg.textContent = value.jq.val();
          CB.set_active_element(key);
          CB.active = value;
        });
        if(value.jq.val()) {
          value.svg.textContent = value.jq.val();
        }
        a.push(value);
        value.jq.parent().fadeIn();
      }
    });
  },
  set_svg_for_text_field: function(e) {
    switch(e.id) {
      case "field_1":
      AB.f.field1.svg = e;
      break;
      case "field_2":
      AB.f.field2.svg = e;
      break;
}
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Where's the code that actually does the binding?

Comment: Anyway just look up jQuery's ".delegate()" method and use that to bind your event handlers.

Comment: @Pointy I added the code that does the binding. Looking at .delegate() now...

Comment: Since you're modifying an element (removing it and re-adding it), at the point where you removed it - bindings stop working. You tried to get around the problem by rebinding everything, but since there's no code that tells us how you did it - my assumption is that the selectors don't match. Also, you should use jQuer's .live() instead of .bind() for these purposes.

Comment: @Pointy or @Michael J.V., I am using ".delegate()" now but the selector isn't grabbing the svn namespace. Ideas?

Comment: Hmm well I personally don't know for sure whether events bubble out of SVG code into the DOM itself. Should be easy to try I guess, but I'm not sure where to even start, being an SVG neophyte (if that).

Comment: Please update the question to clarify if this is using inline svg elements inside an html document, or if it's using e.g `<object>`,`<embed>` or `<iframe>` to include the svg parts.

Comment: I think that because you're using the .delegate() inside an $.each() loop, you're binding it twice, can mess up your code.
Also, if you're using jquery - you can ditch the document.getElementById in favor of $('#id')..

Comment: Yep, fixed. Everything's working now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try .live()

It will bind events to elements that match a selector now and in the future. I have had similar issues when dynamically hiding and showing elements.
[jQuery Live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Great; thanks. I actually went with delegate() but understand live() would have worked too.